# How to add button on top of image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to load image from network and display it fully along with button on top of the image. To achieve this I looked up on various solution and found that this can be done using Stack widget. My implementation is as below

```
    class DisplayImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  DisplayImage({required this.text}) ;

  @override
  State<DisplayImage> createState() => _DisplayImageState();
}

class _DisplayImageState extends State<DisplayImage> {
  
  @override
  initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    _asyncMethod();
    super.initState();

  }
  _asyncMethod() async {
    Image.network(widget.text);
        setState(() {
      dataLoaded = true;
    });
  }
  bool dataLoaded = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (dataLoaded){
      return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Selfie BGchanger"),centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Center(child: Stack(
        children: [Image.network(
                 widget.text,
                 fit: BoxFit.fill,
                 loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                     ImageChunkEvent? loadingProgress) {
                   if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                   return Center(
                     child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                       value: loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes != null
                           ? loadingProgress.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                               loadingProgress.expectedTotalBytes!
                           : null,
                     ),
                   );
                 },
               ),
      
        const SizedBox(height: 50,),
           Align(
             alignment: Alignment(0, .2),
             child: ElevatedButton(child: const Text('Save',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom( shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
                       ),
               primary: Colors.black,
               // padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
               textStyle: TextStyle(
               fontSize: 30,
               fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
             onPressed: () async{
             String url = widget.text;
             var imageId = await ImageDownloader.downloadImage(url);
             if(imageId == null)
             {return;}
               //  ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(const SnackBar(content: Text('Saved to gallery!')));
                Fluttertoast.showToast(msg: "Image saved to Gallery");
             },
             ),
           ),
      ],),
      ),
      );
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator(backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,strokeWidth: 5,);
    }
    
  }
}
```

with this I get image is as below
[image: image1]

save button is on top but what I'm trying to get is as below

Expected:

[image: image2]

full sized image with save button on bottom center

I tried using boxfit.cover with height and width as infinit as below

```
fit: BoxFit.cover,
    // height: double.infinity,
    // width: double.infinity,
```

I got display error

How can I fix this to get expected image ? any help or suggestion on this will be highly appreciated

update:
based on answer suggestion I modified code as above and get output as below
[image: image3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `ElevatedButton` widget with `Positioned`/`Align` widget.

```dart
Align(
  alignment: Alignment(0, .2), //adjust based on your need
  child: ElevatedButton(
```

Also you find more about [Stack](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) , [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget.

```dart
body: Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    Positioned.fill(
        child: Image.network(
      "",
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
    )),
    Align(
      alignment: Alignment(0, .2), // change .2 based on your need
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          await showDatePicker(
            context: context,
            initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.inputOnly,
            initialDate: DateTime.now(),
            firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 33)),
            lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 33)),
          );
        },
        child: Text("Dialog"),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: You can remove the `Column` widget.

Comment: I did these changes and i got output image as shown in edited question please check.I wanted to display it full screen

Comment: Try update approach for image, where it will be using `Positioned.fill`

Comment: Glad to help, explore the attached link for more